# AI suggestions for question editing give 404

Tags: bug, review, suggested-edits

I have just finished writing a question, and I noticed at the bottom of the screen a new "AI suggested edits for your question" section, with a "Get suggestions" button. When I clicked it, I got an exception in a popup:

[image: Error retrieving content formatting update: 404]

Comment: As far as I'm aware, this feature is only available on Stack Overflow. Are you experiencing this on multiple sites?